# Generating a set of pseudorandom numbers satisfying following xor-property?

Tags: algorithm, hash, bit-manipulation, xor

Given a pseudorandom number generator `int64 rand64()`, I would like to build a set of pseudo random numbers. This set should have the property that the XOR combinations of each subset should not result in the value 0.

I'm thinking of following algorithm:

```
count = 0
set = {}
while (count < desiredSetSize)
    set[count] = rand64()
    if propertyIsNotFullfilled(set[0] to set[count])
        continue
    count = count + 1
```

The question is: How can `propertyIsNotFullfilled` be implemented?

**Notes:** The reason why I like to generate such a set is following: I have a hash table where the hash values are generated via [Zobrist hashing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zobrist_hashing). Instead of keeping a boolean value to each hash table entry indicating if the entry is filled, I thought the hash value – which is stored with each entry – is sufficient for this information (0 ... empty, != 0 ... set). There is another reason to carry this information as sentinel value inside the hash-key-table. I'm trying to switch from a AoS (Array of Structure) to a SoA (Structure of Array) memory layout. I'm trying this to avoid padding and to test if there are lesser cache misses. I hope in most cases the access to the hash-key-table is enough (implied that the hash value provides the information if the entry is empty or not).
I also thought about reserving the most significant bit of the hash values for this information but this would reduce the area of possible hash values more than it is necessary. Theoretically the area would be reduced from 2<sup>64</sup> (minus the seninal 0-value) to 2<sup>63</sup>.
One can read the question in the other way: Given a set of 84 pseudorandom numbers, is there any number which can't be generated by XORing any subset of this set, and how to get it? This number can be used as sentinel value.
Now, for what I need it: I have developed a connect four game engine. There are 6 x 7 moves possible for player A and also for player B. Thus there are 84 possible moves (therefore 84 random values needed). The hash value of a board-state is generated by the precalculated random values in the following manner: `hash(board) = randomset[move1] XOR randomset[move2] XOR randomset[move3] ...`

Comment: This has been tried before. The problem is that there always be hash collisions beyond 5 or 6 ply. Composing the Zobrist tables in such a way that the hamming distance between any pair of entries is maximal is the only thing one can do. You could start by imposing a population count of around 1/2 of the number of bits, e.g. 32/64. But once you get beyond the magical n-ply limit, collisions will occur. (even more heavily)

Comment: @wildplasser: Thanks for your comment, but I don't try to avoid collisions, I try to seperate the hash-key from the other table-entry-information. After that I have a `int64` Array with hash-values and a `allOtherInfo` Array with the rest. It would be nice if the `int64` array contains the information, if the entry is empty. Therefore my question.

Comment: If your only goal is to avoid `hash(state) == zero` for all valid states, and use hash==zero as a sentinel value for "invalid": it is generally easier to just spend one extra bit to signify the "is_valid" condition. In some games (go) an empty board (mostly) has a hashvalue of zero, but is a perfectly legal board state. Disallowing a zero hashvalue will cost an awfull amount of corner-case code. Storing one extra "valid" bit in the table is cheaper and cleaner. How big is your "payload" anyway?

Comment: @wildplasser: I have updated the question with more information.

Comment: If the game is connect-four, there are only 3^42 possibilities (of which most are unreachable/impossible. My gut feeling is that you could even *enumerate* all the valid board positions. BTW: you should not hash moves, but positions. Adding a move is equivalent to HASH(new_position) = HASH(previous_position) @@ hash(added_stone), with @@ some operator, probably xor. BTW2 if passing is not allowed the number of reachable positions is even smaller.

Comment: @wildplasser: 3^42 > 2^63 but practically (counting only valid boards) you are right and 63 Bits are certainly enough for connect four. Nevertheless: I'm interested if -- with a given 64 bit random number set and the XOR operation -- one can efficiently verify that all or not all values in the 64 bit number range can be reached. And if not, can you print one of the unobtainable values.

Comment: The board can enumerated within 7*7 bits, counting only the valid positions. It will not be hashing per se, but can be done incrementally. I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> This set should have the property that the XOR combinations of each subset should not result in the value 0.

IMHO this would restrict the maxinum number of subsets to 64 (Pigeonhole principle); for >64 subsets, there will always be a (*non empty*) subset that XORs to zero. For smaller subsets, the property can be fulfilled.

To further illustrate my point: consider a system of 64 equations over 64 unknown variables. Then, add one extra equation. The fact that the equations and variables are booleans does not make the problem different.

--EDIT/UPDATE--: Since the application appears to be the game "connect-four", you could instead enumerate all *possible* configurations. Not being able to code the impossible board configurations will save enough coding space to fit any valid board position in 64 bits:

Encoding the colored stones as {A,B}, and irrelevant as {X} the configuration of a (hight=6) column can be one of:

```
                   X
                X  X
             X  X  X
          X  X  X  X
       X  X  X  X  X
_   A  A  A  A  A  A   <<-- possible configurations for one pile
--+--+--+--+--+--+--+ 
1   1  2  4  8 16 32   <<-- number of combinations of the Xs
               -2 -5   <<-- number of impossible Xs
```

(and similar for B instead of A). The numbers below the piles are the number of posssibilities for the Xs on top, the negative numbers the number of forbidden/impossible configurations. For the column with one A and 4 Xs, every value for the Xs is valid, *except 3*A (the game would already have ended). The same for the rightmost pile: the bottom 3Xs cannot be all A, and X cannot be B for all the Xs.

This leads to a total of 1 + 2 * (63-7) := 113.
(1 is for the empty board, 2 is the number of colors). So: 113 is the number of configurations for one column, fitting well within 7 bit. For 7 columns we'll need 7*7:=49 bits. (we might save one bit for the L/R mirror symmetry, maybe even one for the color symmetry, but that would only complicate things, IMHO).

There still be a lot of coding space wasted (the columns are *not* independent, the number of As on the board is equal to the number of Bs, or one more, etc), but I don't think it would be easy to avoid them. Fortunately, it will not be necessary.

Comment: I'm not quite sure if I can follow you. In my opinion there should be 2^0 + 2^1 + ... + 2^6 - 3 = 127 possibilities for one column (3 are the invalid columns where 6 or 5 in a row). After all, the 7 columns would still fit into a 64 bit variable with one bit reserved for my purpose (therefore thanks for your idea) ant to map a column into the 7 bit value, a lookup table (with the 127 columns) could be used.  Could you please explain how the pigeonhole principle could be applied to my question?

Comment: Not only 5 or 6 in a row are invalid; 4 in a row + XX is invalid (impossible /unreacheable) too, because the game would already have ended. The pigeonhole principle is a bit overstated. In my first edit, I re-stated it using 64 equations with 64 unknowns. The point is: you cannot have more than 64 (orthogonal) equations without having some of the matrix row/columns becoming a function of others.

Comment: Ahh, I see, there is no need to remember boards with 4 in a row. But I am not sure with the equations part. We have a set with 84 numbers and a set with 2^64 numbers and the operation XOR. Now there should be 84*83*...*2*1 equations building other numbers. Ok, my calculator says 84! is about 3.3*10^126 while 2^64 is only about 1.8*10^19 thus the number 0 certainly could be generated in a lot of ways (pigeonhole principle?), or am I wrong?

Comment: Do it on paper using 4 bits (16 possible hashes) and try to create a set of more than 4 orthogonal hashes. (orthogonal in this case means: such that no (nonempty) set of hashes exists that XORs to zero) You could try the set of all 1bit, or the set of 2-bit hashes. BTW: the calculation leading to 113 may have some errors in it, but the number of cases is certainly < 127 ;-)

Comment: I think, I was wrong with the number of possible equations (the number of XOR combinations, given a set with 84 numbers). I have to sum up the combinations! Now I get 1.93E+025 which still is much more then 1.84E+019 (64 Bit range).

Comment: OK: you may do the math, my math is too sloppy: my choices are mostly based on estimates and intuition ;-) BTW: Have you thought yet about board representation ? Two 64 bit bitboards seem logical to me. (it would not surprise me if this game has been solved, BTW2) The enumeration hash will probably need a lookup table, but bitwise tricks seem feasable..

Comment: Well, the game is finished, I am trying to improve it and learn something new about optimizing code. Yes, you are right, I'm using two 64 bit bitboards. You have seen my other question, there are also good answers and I have a lot to learn, hope I have the time for it (my math is also sloppy, hence I made the mistake with the number of equations).

Answer (score 2):

To amplify wildplasser: *every* hash function that be used to distinguish every n-bit string from every other n-bit string cannot have output shorter than n bits. Shorter hash functions are usable because we only have to avoid collisions in the strings that actually arrive, but we cannot hope to make an intelligent choice offline. Just use a cryptographically-secure RNG and one of two things will happen: (i) your code will work as though the RNG were truly random or (ii, unlikely) your code will break and (if it's not bugged) it will act as a distinguisher between the crypto RNG and true randomness, bringing you fame and notoriety.

Answer (score 1):

Amplifying the answer by wildplasser a little bit more, here is an idea how to implement `propertyIsNotFullfilled`.

Represent the set of pseudo-random numbers as a {0,1}-matrix. Perform [Gaussian elimination](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_elimination) (use XOR  instead of usual multiply/subtract operations). If you get matrix where the last row is zero, return `true`, otherwise `false`.

Definitely, this function will return `true` very frequently when size of the set is close to 64. So algorithm in OP is efficient only for relatively small sizes.

To optimize this algorithm, you can keep the result of last Gaussian elimination.